# Nifi LDAP authorization - Multiple groups in search filter through wildcards

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apache-nifi

I am trying to use a search filter for Nifi authorizer via LDAP.
The problem is that the usual search filter syntax does not seem to work.

I currently have nifi working with one of my groups, so getting LDAP to work is not the issue.
I was also able to make it work by using the complete paths to both groups, but I would like to use wildcards.

So I have my AD groups as following

```
prod.xxxx.be
 |--PROD
      |--Groups TIM application entitlements
           |--(A) Nifi - Admin
           |--(A) Nifi - Operator
           |--(A) Nifi - User
```

When using the following it works, and users from both groups are populated in the users list in Nifi UI;

```
<property name="User Search Base">OU=PROD, DC=prod, DC=xxxx, DC=be</property>
<property name="User Object Class">person</property>
<property name="User Search Scope">SUBTREE</property>
<property name="User Search Filter">(&(memberof=CN=(A) Nifi - Admin, OU=Groups TIM Application Entitlements, OU=PROD, DC=prod, DC=xxxx, DC=be)(memberof=CN=(A) Nifi - User, OU=Groups TIM Application Entitlements, OU=PROD, DC=prod, DC=xxxx, DC=be))</property>
<property name="User Identity Attribute">CN</property>
<property name="User Group Name Attribute"></property>
<property name="User Group Name Attribute - Referenced Group Attribute"></property>
```

But since more groups might be added, it does not seem to be very legible.
Therefore it would be great to use wildcards.

I tried many combinations I found at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx but none seem to work for Nifi.

Examples;

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=(A) Nifi*))
```

I even tried to escape the special characters;

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=\28A\29 Nifi*))
```

or

```
(&amp;(objectCategory=group)(cn=\28A\29 Nifi*))
```

Since the config file for authorizers is an XML file, but no luck.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Kristof

Answer (score 0):

We use ambari and needed to clarify the object as character data in the template: